# Adding libraries to a project in xcode - symbols not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker, pjsip

I am trying to make an iphone app in xcode that uses [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org). The problem is I don't know how to link the libraries. This is the first time i am using other libraries so probably i am doing something wrong i just don't know what. :(

I have the ARM version of the libraries in this folder in mac os x.
/Users/kudorgyozo/pjsip_iphone

In Xcode:
I have specified the library and header search paths like this:

for includes:

/Users/kudorgyozo/pjsip_iphone/pjlib/include /Users/kudorgyozo/pjsip_iphone/pjlib-util/include /Users/kudorgyozo/pjsip_iphone/pjmedia/include /Users/kudorgyozo/pjsip_iphone/pjnath/include /Users/kudorgyozo/pjsip_iphone/pjsip/include

for libraries:

/Users/kudorgyozo/pjsip_iphone/pjlib/lib /Users/kudorgyozo/pjsip_iphone/pjlib-util/lib /Users/kudorgyozo/pjsip_iphone/pjmedia/lib /Users/kudorgyozo/pjsip_iphone/pjnath/lib /Users/kudorgyozo/pjsip_iphone/pjsip/lib

and then using the "Other linker flags" :

-lpj-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjlib-util-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjsdp-arm-apple-darwin9  -lpjnath-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjsip-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjsip-simple-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjsip-ua-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjsua-arm-apple-darwin9

Is this OK like this? Because it gives me symbol(s) not found errors. I think no symbol is found from the "included" libraries. I don't know what is wrong i'm just beginning to understand how building an app works under linux based systems i've only done programming in C# before.

EDIT: Here is a list of symbols missing:

```
"_AudioSessionSetProperty", referenced from:
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_set_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_set_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_srtp_deinit", referenced from:
      _pjmedia_srtp_deinit_lib in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(transport_srtp.o)
  "_gsm_encode", referenced from:
      _gsm_codec_encode in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(gsm.o)
  "_AudioComponentInstanceNew", referenced from:
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioSessionAddPropertyListener", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_start in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_speex_decoder_init", referenced from:
      _spx_codec_open in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_res_Resample", referenced from:
      _pjmedia_resample_run in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(resample_resample.o)
      _pjmedia_resample_run in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(resample_resample.o)
  "_speex_bits_write", referenced from:
      _spx_codec_encode in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_gsm_destroy", referenced from:
      _gsm_codec_close in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(gsm.o)
      _gsm_codec_close in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(gsm.o)
  "_AudioComponentInstanceDispose", referenced from:
      _propListener in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_destroy in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioSessionGetProperty", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioComponentFindNext", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_set_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_factory_init in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_speex_encoder_ctl", referenced from:
      _get_speex_info in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _get_speex_info in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _get_speex_info in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _get_speex_info in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _get_speex_info in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _get_speex_info in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _get_speex_info in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _get_speex_info in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_modify in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_modify in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_open in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_open in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_open in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_open in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_open in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_speex_encoder_init", referenced from:
      _get_speex_info in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_open in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_AudioSessionSetActive", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_stop in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_start in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioUnitRender", referenced from:
      _input_callback in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_srtp_dealloc", referenced from:
      _pjmedia_transport_srtp_stop in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(transport_srtp.o)
      _pjmedia_transport_srtp_stop in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(transport_srtp.o)
      _pjmedia_transport_srtp_start in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(transport_srtp.o)
  "_speex_lib_get_mode", referenced from:
      _pjmedia_codec_speex_init in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _pjmedia_codec_speex_init in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_res_SrcLinear", referenced from:
      _pjmedia_resample_run in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(resample_resample.o)
      _pjmedia_resample_run in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(resample_resample.o)
  "_srtp_init", referenced from:
      _pjmedia_srtp_init_lib in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(transport_srtp.o)
  "_speex_bits_init", referenced from:
      _spx_codec_open in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_open in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_AudioUnitSetProperty", referenced from:
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioUnitUninitialize", referenced from:
      _propListener in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_destroy in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_speex_decoder_destroy", referenced from:
      _spx_codec_close in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_AudioUnitInitialize", referenced from:
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_speex_bits_reset", referenced from:
      _spx_codec_encode in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_AudioOutputUnitStop", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_stop in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_stop in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_start in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _interruptionListener in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_srtp_protect_rtcp", referenced from:
      _transport_send_rtcp2 in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(transport_srtp.o)
  "_speex_decode_int", referenced from:
      _spx_codec_recover in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_decode in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_speex_encoder_destroy", referenced from:
      _get_speex_info in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_close in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_gsm_create", referenced from:
      _gsm_codec_open in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(gsm.o)
      _gsm_codec_open in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(gsm.o)
  "_crypto_get_random", referenced from:
      _generate_crypto_attr_value in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(transport_srtp.o)
  "_speex_bits_unpack_unsigned", referenced from:
      _speex_get_next_frame in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _speex_get_next_frame in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _speex_get_next_frame in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _speex_get_next_frame in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _speex_get_next_frame in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_speex_encode_int", referenced from:
      _spx_codec_encode in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_octet_string_hex_string", referenced from:
      _pjmedia_transport_srtp_start in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(transport_srtp.o)
      _pjmedia_transport_srtp_start in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(transport_srtp.o)
  "_AudioSessionInitialize", referenced from:
      _ca_factory_init in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_speex_bits_read_from", referenced from:
      _spx_codec_parse in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_decode in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_speex_nb_mode", referenced from:
      _speex_nb_mode$non_lazy_ptr in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_res_GetXOFF", referenced from:
      _pjmedia_resample_create in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(resample_resample.o)
  "_gsm_decode", referenced from:
      _gsm_codec_decode in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(gsm.o)
  "_speex_mode_query", referenced from:
      _speex_get_next_frame in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_speex_bits_advance", referenced from:
      _speex_get_next_frame in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _speex_get_next_frame in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _speex_get_next_frame in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _speex_get_next_frame in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_decode in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_AudioComponentGetDescription", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_srtp_create", referenced from:
      _pjmedia_transport_srtp_start in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(transport_srtp.o)
      _pjmedia_transport_srtp_start in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(transport_srtp.o)
  "_speex_bits_remaining", referenced from:
      _speex_get_next_frame in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _speex_get_next_frame in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _speex_get_next_frame in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _speex_get_next_frame in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_srtp_unprotect_rtcp", referenced from:
      _srtp_rtcp_cb in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(transport_srtp.o)
  "_AudioOutputUnitStart", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_start in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioSessionRemovePropertyListenerWithUserData", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_destroy in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_speex_decoder_ctl", referenced from:
      _spx_codec_modify in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_open in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_open in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_speex_bits_nbytes", referenced from:
      _spx_codec_encode in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_srtp_protect", referenced from:
      _transport_send_rtp in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(transport_srtp.o)
  "_speex_bits_destroy", referenced from:
      _spx_codec_close in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
      _spx_codec_close in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(speex_codec.o)
  "_srtp_unprotect", referenced from:
      _srtp_rtp_cb in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(transport_srtp.o)
      _srtp_rtp_cb in libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a(transport_srtp.o)
```

Did anybody build pjsip for iphone and created a new project using it?

Comment: What symbols are missing? What library do those symbols come from? Are you linking the library that provides those symbols?

Comment: I am linking the libraries from the pjsip project. All the missing symbols are from these libraries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you are missing (at least) some libraries. From the symbols, I would say that:

- You have probably forgot to add the CoreAudio framework. It is needed to resolve symbols like `AudioUnitRender`
- There should be a RTP library from pjsip, something that contains `pjrtp`. If there is one, then add it to the Other Link Flags. That will fix the `_srtp_XXX` missing symbols.
- There should be a GSM library from pjsip, something that contains `gsm`. If there is one, then add it to the Other Link Flags. That will fix the `_srtp_XXX` missing symbols.
- There should be a Speex library from pjsip, something that contains `speex`. If there is one, then add it to the Other Link Flags. That will fix the `_srtp_XXX` missing symbols.

When encountering missing symbols, the best way to find where they are is:

- Look at the symbol name. Good libraries always prefix their symbols, so from the name you can guess which library holds it.
- If you have a set a static library and you want to know the symbols exported, then you can use the `otool -Sv mystaticlib.a` command. It will displays the table of content for the static library.

Comment: Uhmm.. thanks, i have no idea though how/where to get those other libraries the ones you mentioned. I did try adding coreaudio but i saw that there are 53 errors with and without it, so I removed it. I never verified exactly what symbols were missing after adding it though.

Comment: Adding CoreAudio doesn't solve missing AudioUnitRender...strange

Comment: How do you add CoreAudio ? It is a framework, so adding it as a framework to the project should set the right flags. If you have a folder containing all the pjsip libraries, just run the otool command (see my answer) to see if you can spot the symbols. If the symbol is not there, then you should maybe check on the pjsip side on how to get the RTP, GSM and Speex libraries.

Comment: For CoreAudio i just added like any other framework from apple: right click on frameworks and add existing frameworks and selected coreaudio.

Answer (score 3):

It seems I was stupid and didn't observe a folder called third-party. There are the missing libraries. In the docs theye were NOT mentioned so I didn't even bother looking in the other folders. I still have missing symbols but fewer (I think). I also included CoreAudio, I don't think it helped. I modified my project:

Added to the other linker flags:

```
-lg7221codec-arm-apple-darwin9 -lgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9 -lilbccodec-arm-apple-darwin9 -lmilenage-arm-apple-darwin9 -lresample-arm-apple-darwin9 -lspeex-arm-apple-darwin9 -lsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9
```

And to the library search paths:

```
/Users/kudorgyozo/pjsip_iphone/third_party/lib
```

I don't have to modify the header search path's or include new headers i THINK.

Here's what is missing now:

```
  "_AudioSessionSetProperty", referenced from:
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_set_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_set_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioComponentInstanceNew", referenced from:
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioSessionAddPropertyListener", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_start in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioComponentInstanceDispose", referenced from:
      _propListener in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_destroy in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioSessionGetProperty", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioComponentFindNext", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_set_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_factory_init in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioSessionSetActive", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_stop in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_start in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioUnitRender", referenced from:
      _input_callback in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioUnitSetProperty", referenced from:
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioUnitUninitialize", referenced from:
      _propListener in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_destroy in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioUnitInitialize", referenced from:
      _create_audio_unit in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioOutputUnitStop", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_stop in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_stop in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _ca_stream_start in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
      _interruptionListener in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioSessionInitialize", referenced from:
      _ca_factory_init in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioComponentGetDescription", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_get_cap in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioOutputUnitStart", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_start in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
  "_AudioSessionRemovePropertyListenerWithUserData", referenced from:
      _ca_stream_destroy in libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(coreaudio_dev.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

It seems to me all are from this file libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a but i have included it in the linker flags an in the lib search paths.

I was able to build it successfully. The missing framework was AudioToolbox. Did a google search for AudioSessionSetProperty and that is how i found out. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Add every static library to your xcode project which has been built during build of Pjsip libraries. Then add every framework related with Audio and Core frameworks.